# $G$ is an infinite abelian group such that $G \cong H$ for every non trivial subgroup $H$ of $G$ , then is $G$ cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, infinite-groups

If $G$ is an infinite abelian group such that $G \cong H$ for every non trivial subgroup $H$ of $G$ , then is $G$ cyclic , or equivalently asking , then is $[G:H]$ finite for every non trivial subgroup $H$ of $G$ ?

I know that the assumption holds for $G=\mathbb Z$ , so I am asking is this the only group upto isomorphism for which the stated assumption holds . Also I know that if for an infinite group $G$ , $[G:H]$ is finite for every non trivial subgroup of $H$ then $G$ is cyclic .

Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74329

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\in G$, $x\ne0$; then $\langle x\rangle$ is a (non trivial) cyclic subgroup of $G$. Since $\langle x\rangle\cong G$, we have that $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: off-course .. and I missed that :) thanks

Comment: @user228169 Now a quiz: does there exist a *non cyclic* abelian group such that its proper (non trivial) subgroups are all cyclic? Can you classify such groups, if they exist?

Comment: For prime $p$ , all proper subgroups of the abelian non cyclic group $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$ is cyclic . Let me think about the classification and an infinite example ..

Comment: Any finite abelian non cyclic group with the stated property is of the form $\mathbb Z_p \times Z_p$ for some prime $p$

Comment: @user228169 Correct. Infinite groups are a bit harder. 

Comment: yeah I can clearly see and feel that , its wrecking my head :) , thanks by the way for the nice question ( which turned out to be a bit more than just a quiz ... :p ) . And could you please look at this question for a little bit  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765003/g-be-an-infinite-group-such-that-aut-g-2-then-is-g-cyclic?rq=1 , thanks again

Comment: @user228169 For infinite groups, the answer should be: the rationals and the Prüfer groups (the indecomposable direct summands of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$).